# MOV format specification

Tags: quicktime, specifications, file-format

Is there a documentation for reading Quicktime MOV file without using Quicktime SDK?

Comment: This is on a Need-to-know basis. And Lord Steve of Jobs doesn't need you to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wotsit.org](http://www.wotsit.org/) has [4 documents](http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?search=mov&button=GO) about the MOV file format.

Comment: +1, this site deserves it, they have been tops for a long, long time.

Answer (score 8):

Apple has released a [QuickTime File Format Specification](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/qtff/qtff.pdf).

Comment: New link is currently [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFPreface/qtffPreface.html)

Answer (score 1):

[If you are particularly industrious, and are looking to rewrite quicktime, you can read the specification from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/qtff/qtff.pdf).

Or, you can just put a wrapper around an existing library such as [Libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec) like [mPlayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer) does.

Comment: No I don't want to rewrite quicktime, i just want to extract an information in the header!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source for mplayer, ffmpeg, vlc.

Should be some kind of documentation there.